# js / html conditional if cond=' ....'

Tags: javascript, html, widget, blogger

I'm a beginner in html/java... so maybe this will look easy for most of you... but not for me yet!

Working with: Blogger:  blogspot + widget HTML

Code Part 1 : this is a part of the widget "drop down vertical menu" ... I select a country/language  and the last line  ( < span id="result">< /span> ) will display/write the choice i have made.
It's working good up to that point.

Code Part 2: in my futur blog, I would like to display links of the selected language, below the menu, after having made language selection.
Problem: I don't know how to build/write the html block  < b:if cond=' .....  < /b:if>

Ex:  I mouse-select English on my menu...  So the line  < span id="result" >< /span>   will display/show the result variable id:  EN

I want to replace this line by conditionals blocks, with links from my blog corresponding to the selected language.

So, the question: how to make/code this blocks   < b:if cond=' ????  ......  < /b:if>   to display only the corresponding language links parts ?

Thanks in advance
Steve

---------------/ part 1 = ok   ( this is only the end code part...
Full code got from here: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/reinventing-a-drop-down-with-css-and-jquery/

```
              $(document).ready(function() {
              $(".dropdown img.flag").addClass("flagvisibility");

              $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
                  $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
              });

              $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
                  var text = $(this).html();
                  $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
                  $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
                  $("#result").html(getSelectedValue("sample"));
              });

              function getSelectedValue(id) {
                  return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
              }

              $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
                  var $clicked = $(e.target);
                  if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
                      $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
              });


              $("#flagSwitcher").click(function() {
                  $(".dropdown img.flag").toggleClass("flagvisibility");
              });
          });
      </script>
```

```
      <p class="desc"></p>
      <dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
          <dt><a href="#"><span>Select : <br />  Country / Language</span></a></dt>
          <dd>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">English<img class="flag" src="en.png" alt="" /><span class="value">EN</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">France<img class="flag" src="fr.png" alt="" /><span class="value">FR</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deutsch<img class="flag" src="de.png" alt="" /><span class="value">DE</span></a></li>
              </ul>
          </dd>
      </dl>
  </h1>


<span id="result"></span>
```

-----------\ end part 1: OK

------ Problem : part 2

```
 if cond=  id="result" == "EN"' >  
 {
 <a href="#" target="_blank">My english page1 </a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank">My english page2 </a>
 <a href="#" target="_blank">My english page3 </a>
 }
```

The " part 1 "  menu code is coming from here:
http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/reinventing-a-drop-down-with-css-and-jquery/